# syntax to guard against SQL-injection of named identifiers

Tags: psycopg2, sql-injection, identifier

I'm reading the psycopg2 [documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute) & wondering how to parametrize  SQL identifiers of tables with a name? Here is an example:

```py
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect()
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(
   "SELECT * FROM %(my_table)s LIMIT %(my_limit)s;"
   vars={
       "my_limit": 42,                    # parametrizing literals works fine.
       "my_table": sql.Identifier("foo"), # how to do same with named identifiers?
   }
)
```

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'Identifier'
```

I know I could use positional parameters `%s` or `{}` but I would like the query to mix and match identifiers with literals with a named mapping.

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM %(my_table)s LIMIT %(my_limit)s;"` is **not** "parameterizing your query". That's still string interpolation.

Comment: Also, the fact that you try to parameterize table names means that either your database design, or your approach itself is lacking. You should never need to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the still interpolation tip. I am only parametrizing identifiers just to be defensive in case the internal variables ever get exposed.

Comment: But you should not parameterize your SQL identifiers *at all*. Your SQL code should be completely static except for value placeholders. What's the point of having queries with replaceable table names?

Comment: (I just looked at the docs and psycopg2 apparently mimics Python's string interpolation syntax, but it does not actually *do* string interpolation. Good to know, had me fooled initially.)

Comment: Perhaps a bit niche but some use-cases for parametrizing identifiers that come to mind are: common code to build internal queries, encapsulating DB naming details within DAO layers, referencing cross-transaction temporary tables (with internally generated names), ..

Comment: Ok, but all these things use table names that are strictly application-internal, and therefore trusted - you could actually use straight string-interpolation for this. I was thinking more of a "uses supplies the table name" scenario, which really should not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did it for me:

```py
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql

conn = psycopg2.connect()
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql.SQL(
    "SELECT * FROM {my_table} LIMIT {my_limit};"
  ).format(
    my_limit = sql.Literal(42),
    my_table = sql.Identifier("foo"),
  ).as_string(conn)
)
```